# How to calculate particle trajectory in spherical coordinates

Tags: geometry, spherical-coordinates

I need to reconstruct particle tracks starting from a generating disk and entering a detector. The geometry of the setup is shown in the schematic below.
[image: problem schematic]

Variables I know:

$D$: the distance of generating disk to detector center.

$\theta, \Phi$: azimuth and zenith angles for the orientation of the disk

$R$: on_disk radius. The distance of the particle starting point to the center of the disk

$\Theta$: on_disk azimuth angle

I am assuming that the track will have an equation $f(x(t),y(t),z(t)) = p_0 + ut$ where $p_0$ is the starting point position and $u$ the velocity times a vector normal to the disk. But I am having some trouble calculating the normal vector and the starting point. Any ideas?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system is fairly exhaustive. Use atan2 to choose quadrants.

Comment: Why not cylindrical coordinates ?

Comment: @JeanMarie i can choose whatever coordinate system i want.

Comment: Looks like the disc is perpendicular to the vector joining  detector center with disc center. If so, the normal  you need is just proportional to that vector. If not so, you need two more angles to describe the position of the disc.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca thank you that is useful. Then for the starting point i have two vectors. one from detector center to disk center and one from disk center to point. can i just convert them both to cartesians and add them?

Comment: You can do so, but you must be careful when you convert on-disk polar coordinates $(R,\Theta)$ to cartesian coordinates: you must rotate a point about a line normal to the disk.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca could you please elaborate a bit? it sounds like some matrix multilication but what would be my matrices?